# Is RotCFD or Ansys Fluent better to capture the wake pattern far downstream of a flow in the case of a rotating blade?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ansys, cfd, fluid

My main constraint is that the wake pattern to be worked on is far downstream.
Which one will give me more accurate results?
Will these two work well for the far wake at all?

Comment: What will you compare these results against to check the accuracy?